USB won't mount - Error mounting /dev/dm-0 at /media/user/ Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock
Trying to access files on a usb drive on Ubuntu 24.
The error: Error mounting /dev/dm-0 at /media/user/ Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/ bitlk-? missing codepage or helper program, or other error
This happened before and there shouldn't be anything wrong with the USB.
I tried
sudo ntfsfix --clear-dirty /dev/sdc1
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.

The usb is not corrupted, I can access the files on Windows.
I can see the usb drive disk here with lsblk:
lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
...
sdc                            8:32   1 116.1G  0 disk  
└─sdc1                         8:33   1 116.1G  0 part  
  └─bitlk-61b30afdd-7b32-4b61-1111-0ee2a5d67e8f
                             252:0    0 116.1G  0 crypt 
...

Any other commands to try? This happened before and a simple command to refresh the usb mount or similar command fixed the problem immediately

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1512710/wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-just-installed-lubuntu-24-04
This is a possible solution using the Disks app, editing the mount options and turning off 'user session defaults'.
I can't figure out why this is an intermittent problem with usb drives on Ubuntu.

Your sdc1 looks like a bitlocker-encrypted partition, you need software for this. But I don't have any experience of this. I think you might refer to  this
