Problem opening Windows 11 partition on Ubuntu 24.10 dual boot system
After upgrading from 24.04 to 24.10 I can not open my Windows partition with Files (Nautilus).  (In 24.04 the partition could be seen as an Other Location.) The partition is on a second SSD dedicated to Windows. It shows at the bottom of the sidebar, but when I try to open it I get the message
Unable to access "511 GB Volume"

Error mounting /dev/sdb3 at /media/rquint/<partition's UUID> 
  wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb3,
  missing code page or helper program, or other error

The partition is ok.  I've run chkdsk, and confirmed fast startup and hibernation are disabled, I've done a clean shutdown.  I've booted Windows and Ubuntu several times. I have successfully mounted and accessed the partition by creating a folder /mnt/Windows and running sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb3 /mnt/Windows and then unmounted it.
Is this a bug in 24.10 or a planned new behaviour?

Solution due to @ENIAC at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1512710/
